# Realex Payments HPP in Magento 2.3 - 302 Redirect?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am currently upgrading our Magento 1.9.x store to Magento 2.3. I have been working to get everything up and running, including installing all extensions (or equivalent) used previously on our old Magento install.

I am having an issue with Global Payments - Realex Payments Extension, as provide by them and on Magento Marketplace.

I am in sandbox mode, using test cards with our sandbox credential set up. I have installed via composer & also attempted a manual install with the same error.

Error received after passing through the checkout

> Your transaction has been successful but there was a problem connecting back to the merchant's web site. Please contact the merchant and advise them that you received this error message.

Realex support stated this

> You'll see from the transaction log I sent that you're trying to connect back to http://*************/realexpayments_hpp/process/result The http status code error is 302 which indicates that there is a redirect on this page. The page should be plain html/css.

I setup a fresh Magento install without any extensions, with the same result. Global payments are denying an issue with the extension and I am unable to find why this will be happening.

Is anyone else able to shed any light on this or is anyone using the extension? The debug log doesn't state anything to be concerned about.

Comment: What happens when you try to go to that address in your browser directly? Check if there’s any redirects happening, by looking at the network panel. Maybe this is simply missing a trailing slash or something.

Comment: Just redirects to the shopping cart, I imagine on a successful transaction, would go through to the standard success confirmation page?

Comment: Hm, okay, but that might also be due to other factors, such that this was a GET request, but it expects a POST (if this is supposed to be a server-side callback, not a client-side redirect URL.) I guess you might have to delve into this a little deeper and do some debugging to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Realex Payment “Controller/Process?Result” is POST method
In Magento 2.3, controller must implement CsrfAwareActionInterface and 2 of its methods

```
public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
{
    return null;
}

public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
{
    return true;
}
```

I got sample module for in on [Github](https://github.com/magecommunity/RealexPayments) for Realex Payment 2.3 compatibility

http://magecommunity.com/realex-payments-302-redirect-issue-in-magento-2-3/